# Send an Email if process stops - Windows

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-server

My windows server runs two projects (Node and Golang). Both projects start using cmd commands. Sometimes one of the projects get stopped. So I'm currently trying to implement an solution for that. Which is if one of those projects exited with an error I want to send an email to notify that. I tried Windows task scheduler but send email option is deprecated in Windows 10. Is there any alternatives I can use?

Comment: Do you really need an email or wouldn't it be easier to simply restart the process? You could e.g. make a trigger running every minute to start the process and under settings you define to not start a new instance if already one is running. That way a new process is started after a minute when it fails.

Comment: Create a PowerShell script and schedule the script in Task Scheduler. Refer this link : https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1653384-task-scheduler-send-and-e-mail-deprecated-any-other-ways-to-send-email